# Dart Convert List as Map Entry for JSON Encoding

Tags: dart

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615241/dart-json-decoder) before about Dart encoding/decoding to JSON, however, the libraries that were suggested were not complete and I decided to manually handle that.

The objective is to convert these objects to a map.

```dart
class Parent extends Object {
   int id;
   String name;
   List<Child> listChild = new List<Child>();
   Map toMap() => {"id":id, "name":name, "listChild":listChild};
}

class Child extends Object {
   int id;
   String childName;
   Map toMap() => {"id":id, "childName":childName};   
}
```

When doing

```dart
print(JSON.encode(parent.toMap()));
```

I am seeing it go here, any suggestion how to make this work?

```dart
if (!stringifyJsonValue(object)) {
  checkCycle(object);
  try {
    var customJson = _toEncodable(object);
    if (!stringifyJsonValue(customJson)) {
      throw new JsonUnsupportedObjectError(object);
    }
    _removeSeen(object);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new JsonUnsupportedObjectError(object, cause : e);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename `Map toMap()` into `Map toJson()` and it will work fine. =)

```dart
void encode() {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    Child c1 = new Child();
    c1 ..id = 1 ..childName = "Alex";

    Child c2 = new Child();
    c2 ..id = 2 ..childName = "John";

    Child c3 = new Child();
    c3 ..id = 3 ..childName = "Jane";

    p ..id = 1 ..name = "Lisa" ..listChild = [c1,c2,c3];

    String json = JSON.encode(p);
    print(json);
}

class Parent extends Object {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Child> listChild = new List<Child>();
    Map toJson() => {"id":id, "name":name, "listChild":listChild};
}

class Child extends Object {
    int id;
    String childName;
    Map toJson() => {"id":id, "childName":childName};   
}
```

Comment: that solved my problem. I've been struggling to find some documentation on the convert API that clearly mentions object to json conversion, can you share the link that you got this from?

Comment: Hi, good to hear that it helped! I think I looked at the sourcee code of json.dart to find out, but I am nur sure anymore: https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10914009/patch/7001/6002

Comment: The documentation is on JSON.encode: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-convert.JsonCodec#id_encode . It states that any object that doesn't directly correspond to a JSON literal (num/String/bool/null/List/Map) will be sent through the toEncodable function. You can change `JSON.encode(p)` to `JSON.encode(p, (x)=>x.toMap())` and it should work for objects with a toMap method.

Answer (score 8):

```dart
Map toMap() => {"id":id, "name":name: "listChild": listChild.map((c) => c.toJson().toList())};
```

is valid for JSON.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

...

String json = JSON.encode(toMap());
```

You can also use the `toEncodeable` callback - see [How to convert DateTime object to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813942)

Comment: Hi @Gunter, i've modified my question. I tried your suggestion but am getting an exception.

Comment: What exception. Can you please add the details?

Comment: Its on the question. JsonUnsupportedObject.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention. The problem is not the list but the objects in the list. I updated the code but haven't tested it. You need to convert the `Child` items in the List to maps individually.

Comment: But you can see the code above the child object just contains an int, string and a toMap method. Ia anything wrong with that?

Comment: No but `JSON.encode()` doesn't know that. It sees an unsupported object and stops.

Answer (score 5):

If your class structure does not contain's any inner class then follow

```
class Data{

  String name;
  String type;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'type': type
      };
}
```

If your class uses inner class structure

```
class QuestionTag {
  String name;
  List<SubTags> listSubTags;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'listSubTags': listSubTags.map((tag) => tag.toJson()).toList()
      };
}

class SubTags {
  String tagName;
  String tagDesc;

  SubTags(this.tagName, this.tagDesc);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'tagName': tagName,
        'tagDesc': tagDesc,
      };
}
```